# Setting a keyboard shortcut to trigger a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple Chrome extension that I can't get to be triggered by a keyboard shortcut. My extension looks at a matching URL, extracts the customer ID from it, then appends that customer ID to a Tableau Online URL and redirects the page or opens a new tab to that page on Tableau Online.

My manifest.json and runtime.js files have:

manifest.js

```
...
"permissions": ["storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab", "tabs"],
...
"commands": { "open_tableau_report": 
  { "suggested_key": { "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y" }, "description": "Open Tableau Report"}},
...
```

runtime.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (msg.text) {
        switch (msg.text) {
        case 'open_tableau_report':
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
                chrome.storage.sync.get(['tableauBaseUrl','vsExtTarget'], function(items){
                    let url = tabs[0].url;
                    let vsid = url.match(/https:\/\/foo.com\/customers\/detail\/([a-f0-9]{24})/)[1];
                    target = items.vsExtTarget;
                    tableau_base_url = items.tableauBaseUrl;
                    if (target == 'new')  {
                        chrome.tabs.create({url: tableau_base_url + vsid}); // new tab
                    } else {
                        chrome.tabs.update({url: tableau_base_url + vsid}); // same tab
                    }
                });
            });
            break;
        default:
            sendResponse('');
        }
    }
});
```

When I trigger the shortcut key combo I see this error in the Chrome DevTools I see the error:

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://pdjmgncpljjageanemimmdfpdokdfodm/main.js:5:16
```

Having added "tabs" to the permissions I'm assuming that the Chrome extension simply doesn't have access to `chrome.tabs`? How can I rework the code in runtime.js to be responsive to the keyboard shortcut? Thank you!!

Comment: it IS responsive to the keyboard shortcut - your code is executed, and has an error - you should try to solve the error that is given to you, not assume the keyboard shortcut didn't work (it did, your code ran)

Comment: 1) Instead of onMessage use chrome.commands.onCommand as shown in the documentation, 2) Put this code in the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).